# How to point to control?

Tags: c#, winforms

i've 6 label controls in a form: label1, label2...label6. 
How to 'refer' to the control in a loop like this:

```
for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {
   label[i].text = ...;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific? You are already referring to the labels, so I don't see what you want. Also: it's a good idea to probably start your `i` at 0.

Comment: why not put your controls into an array? :-)

Comment: Ok Vlad: how to put them into the array ? ;)

Comment: Add class member `List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();`, and add to your constructor: `controls.Add(label1); controls.Add(label2); controls.Add(label3); controls.Add(label4); controls.Add(label5); controls.Add(label6);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume this is WinForms and that your "labels" are controls - the `Form` has a `Controls` property, which is a collection of controls associated with that container, so, we ought to be able to use Linq to query this, get the controls of the type we want, then iterate them, as such:

```
using System.Linq;

var labels = from control in Controls where control is Label select control;

for (i = 1; i <= controls.Count; i++)
{
   labels[i].text = i.ToString();
}
```

A little rough, but you aren't very specific - it should be a decent starting point if nothing else.

EDIT:

OK, I thought I'd take the time to look into it, and `Form.Controls` doesn't like being used in Linq (in that straightforward way, at least), so as an alternative, this should help:

```
private List<Label> GetLabels()
{
    var result = new List<Label>();
    foreach (var control in Controls)
    {
        if (control is Label)
        {
            result.Add(control as Label);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above method could even be factored in a genericised way rather simply; but then you can proceed:

```
var labels = GetLabels();
for (int i = 0; i <= labels.Count; i++)
{
    labels[i].Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: These snippets have the considerable problem that they don't control the order of the labels.  This tends to break later, very hard to diagnose.  Writing it explicitly with a simple array initialization is best.

Comment: @Hans True, but I don't expect this to be the extent of the logic within the loop; presumably (and ideally) the OP will know (or find out) _something_ about the control they're about to manipulate. An index in this case might well be enough, I've no idea. Worth pointing out, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Label []labels={Label1,Label2,Label3};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
for (int n = 1; n < 4; n++)
{
    Control[] Temp = Controls.Find("Label" + n, false);
    Temp[0].Text = n.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this:-

```
    int y = 0;
    int index = 0;

    Label[] labels = new Label[6];

    foreach (Student std in StudentList)
    {
            labels[index] = new Label();

            labels[index].Text = std.Name;

            labels[index].ForeColor = Color.Red;

            labels[index].Location = new Point(0, y);

            labels[index].Size = new Size(50, 12);

            y = y + 10;
            ++index;
    }

    // Add the Label control to the form.
    mPanel.Controls.AddRange(labels);
```